# Technical detail about a coordinate vector based at t in a manifold M

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, vectors, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a(n abstract) smooth manifold and $\alpha(t):\mathbb{R}\to \phi(U)\subseteq{\mathbb{R}^n}$ be defined by $\alpha(t)=(t+b_1,b_2,...,b_n)$ 
for suitable constants $b_i$.
I would like to know whether this object
$$\dot{\gamma}(t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}\Bigg|_{\gamma(t)}$$

is **something different** from the inverse image $\phi^{-1}\circ\alpha$ near $t$ of the **representation** of $\gamma$ which is just $\alpha$ by the inverse of the chart $(U,\phi)$.

Or whether it is **literally** the same?

Comment: This seems a bit muddled. So $\gamma(t) = \phi^{-1}\circ\alpha(t)$ is the curve in $M$. $\alpha = \phi\circ\gamma$ is its representation in the chart $\phi$ (not inverse). But, yes, the convention is that if we write $\phi = (x^1,\dots,x^n)$, then $\partial/\partial x^1$ is the tangent vector to the $x^1$-curve in $M$ passing through your point. That's what your curve $\gamma$ is.

Comment: Could you put "the inverse image... near $t$ of the representation of $ \gamma$..." in functional notation? It is hard for me to tell what you  mean.

Comment: I would like to make clear what is **really meant** by a **tangent vector** when we deal by an **abstract** manifold, i.e. not the one embedded in $\mathbb{R}^N$.Is a tangent vector **literally** the same as the curve $\gamma$ **itself**?